# How to edit grid size using system plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I would like to edit grid size. I've written simple system plugin to do this, but it's not working for some reason.

When I print out the cell count from grid 0 I get 2000 as expected. But in Gazebo there's no change to default grid size. It's still grid consisting of 20x20 cells.

Here's the code:

```
#include <gazebo/rendering/rendering.hh>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <ros/ros.h>

namespace gazebo{
    class GridPlugin : public SystemPlugin {
    public:
        void Load(int /*_argc*/, char ** /*_argv*/){
            this->connections_.push_back(event::Events::ConnectRender(boost::bind(&GridPlugin::Update, this)));
        }
    private:
        void Update(){
            rendering::ScenePtr scene = rendering::get_scene();

            if(!scene || !scene->Initialized()){
                return;
            }

            auto grid = scene->GetGrid(0);
            if(!grid) return;
            grid->SetCellCount(2000);

            ROS_INFO("cell count: %d", scene->GetGrid(0)->GetCellCount());
        }

    private:
        std::vector<event::ConnectionPtr> connections_;
    };

    GZ_REGISTER_SYSTEM_PLUGIN(GridPlugin)
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15912/how-to-edit-grid-size-using-system-plugin/) by [l4ncelot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2904/l4ncelot/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are usually two scenes in Gazebo, one for gzserver and another for gzclient. It is possible that the scene you're changing is in the server. You could try using a GUI plugin to be sure you're on the client process.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2904/l4ncelot/) on 2017-04-18**:
Is there a way to check whether I'm in server or client scene through system plugin? What's GUI plugin, I've never heard about it and I cannot find example of it on gazebo site.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-04-18**:
Here's a tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gui_overlay

I'm not sure about verifying whether the scene is on client or server

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2904/l4ncelot/) on 2017-04-19**:
Thank you. I've encountered one problem while writing the GUIplugin. How do I compile the plugin in ROS package? When I try to create SHARED library I get this error:

/usr/include/gazebo-7/gazebo/gui/qt.h:23:17: fatal error: QtGui: No such file or directory

I think I need to link qt libraries there, but I'm not quite sure.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2904/l4ncelot/) on 2017-04-19**:
Oh sorry, there's already CMakeLists file in your example. I didn't see that :).